# Spring 4 Hikari Connection Pool ClassCastException

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc, google-cloud-sql, hikaricp

I wish to use Hikari Connection Pool in my Spring 4 application. The database is Google Cloud SQL Postgres database.

I have the following dependency in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my applicationContext.xml, I have:

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:postgresql://google/mydatabase?cloudSqlInstance=projectId:regionName:myInstance&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory</prop>
            <prop key="user">postgres</prop>
            <prop key="password">mypassword</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.postgresql.Driver to javax.sql.DataSource
        at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:102)
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The `org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver` is not a `javax.sql.DataSource`, it is a `java.sql.Driver`, so it doesn't work for the property `dataSourceClassName` as that property expects a `javax.sql.DataSource` class name.

If you want to use the driver (and not a `DataSource`), then you should use the property `driverClassName`.

So:

```xml
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Hikari recommended datasource for PostgreSQL: [org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP)

```
 <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" />
```

> **Database Driver  DataSource class**
>
> PostgreSQL pgjdbc-ng   com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource
>   PostgreSQL  PostgreSQL  org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource

Comment: With this, I'm getting `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cloudSqlInstance property not set. Please specify this property in the JDBC URL or the connection Properties with value in form "project:region:instance"` Do we have to use `<prop key="jdbcUrl">` instead of `<prop key="url">`?

Comment: @user5155835 there was an issue that was fixed see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/1267

Comment: we're not using spring-cloud. Does that mean this is an issue in Cloud SQL JDBC SocketFactory?